# app runs on iOS 4, does not on iPad after updating ad hoc provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ipad, adhoc

The app uses features supported on iOS 4 (sending SMS), but should run on iPad as well. That was something that I spent time researching but found the way to make it work by setting link to weak. Before it was resolved, the app could not start on iPad, flash screen appears and app crashes. After that everything was okay and it worked with ad hoc provisioning. Recently I added another device to the ad hoc provisioning and suddenly the app crashes on iPad once again. It works as expected on simulator ( target is simulator), but crashes on the device ( target is device) . I did try to rebuild the app, removed old provisioning profile ( which kept appearing again ), then created new adhoc provisioning. The result is the same. The app works on iphone running ios 4, and can not start on iPad.

Suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the suggestion that the app worked on iPad was wrong. The issue was resolved my linking all the framework as weak.